# How can I check if an element exists in array of objects using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Suppose I have the following array:

```
var users = [
    {id: 3, name: "sally"}
    {id: 5, name: "bob"}
    {id: 40, name: "joe"}
    {id: 67, name: "eve"}
    {id: 168, name: "bob"}
    {id: 269, name: "amanda"}
]
```

I need to run a loadash function that would return true if, for example name == "bob" exists in the array regardless of how many times it exists in the array.

I would like to know is if there is one function I could use, possible using lodash (not necessarily though) that would return true or false indicating the existence of an object in the target array.

Thanks

Comment: This is very unclear.  The title for instance says "get true *or* false", the question only says "return true".  Given the array you provide, what is the output you expect?   I'm probably not going out on a limb saying you will probably want to use either `map`  or `filter`.  If you just want to know if "bob" is in the array whatsoever, `some` will work (or `_.find`)

Comment: In lodash `_.find(users, ['name', 'Bob"]);`

Comment: Using native JS: `var test = users.some(u => u.name === "bob");`.

Comment: @George Jempty I only need it to return true. I guess find is the correct answer.

Comment: @user3808307 See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: Using lodash: `var test = _.some(users, ["name", "bob"]);`.

Comment: Thank you @ibrahim mahrir! I guess some is better than find. That is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You're welcome! I've added a lodash way too. I recommend you use lodash's version as you are already using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the filter function to search through your array and find the object with the given name.

```
var users = [
    {id: 3, name: "sally"},
    {id: 5, name: "bob"},
    {id: 40, name: "joe"},
    {id: 67, name: "eve"},
    {id: 168, name: "bob"},
    {id: 269, name: "amanda"},
];

function find(name) {
    return !!users.find(x => x.name === name);
}
```

More about the filter function can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: you could add a bit explanation

Comment: @entio explain a bit further please

Comment: @entio i misunderstood your comment, added a link and basic explanation